# Pressing Enter should simply insert a space when adding wildcard tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, autocomplete, wildcards, tag-dropdown

When I enter in something into  the favorites or ignored input i get something that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of suggested tags drop-down]

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after this point, the system pulls up the dropdown, chooses the first highlighted and then adds a space for me to add another tag. Note that the suggestions ignore the trailing dash..

So if I then type a `*` for a wildcard after I typed `jquery-` (so I now have `jquery-*`), this is also ignored by the autocompletion, leaving the previous suggestions intact. If I then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will again insert the selected suggestion from the dropdown and append a space.

I suggest that **when a user types a `*` the autocomplete should not match anything**, and when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> it should just add a space next to the text that was typed (`jquery-*` my example) and allow for another tag to be entered.

Comment: Previously asked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99287/enter-key-does-not-save-wildcards-on-favorites-and-on-ignores) and closed (incorrectly) as a duplicate. I asked Neal to re-ask it with more information to avoid dragging history and answers along with it.

Comment: While I agree with the premise, I think that the '*' isn't necessarily being ignored, since all of the 'jquery-' tags would be valid with a *.