# Standardize the tag used for the tag suggestion dialog

Tags: feature-request, retag-request, tag-dropdown, tag-autocomplete

Please <strike>make two of these synonyms of the third (here on Meta)</strike> update the tag wikis to clarify what each of the tags is for:

<strike>[tag-suggestions](/questions/tagged/tag-suggestions)</strike> [tag-dropdown](/questions/tagged/tag-dropdown) [tag-selector](/questions/tagged/tag-selector)

**Update**:

They aren't all intended to be the same, apparently. bemace clarified this [below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101558/standardize-the-tag-used-for-the-tag-suggestion-dialog/101737#101737). However, I've seen the tags used on questions as though they were the same. I'll go find them and edit the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added wiki excerpts to [tag-selector](/questions/tagged/tag-selector) and [tag-dropdown](/questions/tagged/tag-dropdown) that will hopefully clarify the distinction.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't realize there was a distinction between the two. I'll go offer some edit suggestions so everything's tagged correctly.

Comment: Is the widget displayed in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99459/pressing-enter-should-simply-insert-a-space-when-adding-wildcard-tags) [tag-suggestions], then?

Answer (score 1):

I vote for [tag-selector](/questions/tagged/tag-selector).

Comment: Any other reason than the fact that you created it?

Comment: @balpha, I created it because I liked it, and I already have a taxonimist badge.  I think it says what the functionality is the best, since it's all about selecting tags.  My second choice would be tag-dropdown.  We definitely need the name to reflect that it's about a UI component.  Tag-suggestions is a much broader topic than just the new selector.

Answer (score 1):

[tag-suggestions](/questions/tagged/tag-suggestions) is not the same as the others.  The suggested tags don't necessarily have anything to do with the selector/dropdown.